# all regressions: coefficients interpretation

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, nonparametric, interpretation

good morning to all, I open this topic with the intention of being useful to me but also to many in my situational. I would like to clarify the "interpretation" of the coefficients in the regression. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

-regr.lineare: increasing unit X1, the Y variable increases by beta1

-regr. logit: increasing unit X1, the Y odds ratio increases by exp (beta1)

-regr. poisson: increasing unit X1, the Y variable increases by exp (beta1)

-regr. poisson with offset (rate): the higher unit X1, the variable Y
(Rate) increases by exp (beta1)

-regr. cox: increasing unit X1, hazard ratio increases by exp (beta1)

-regr. quantile: increasing unit X1, the median value (or the 1,3,4 quartile) of the Y variable increases by beta1

I tried to be simple. Here I would like first thing to understand if I wrote something wrong. Then I would understand how you interpret the coefficients when using several distributions such as "range, invergamma, negative binomial etc ..." the distrubizioni less common. also the interpretation even in the case of non-parametric regression.
thank you